# Elementary divisibility problem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I was doing an elementary number theory exercise in a certain text, and i came across this problem:

Is there an even integer $n$ such that $1^n + 2^n + \cdots +m^n$ divides $(m+1)^{n}(m^n - 2^n)$, where $m >2$  ?

Comment: Is $m$ fixed or are you looking for an integer $n$ such that the statement holds for all $m>1$? In case $m$ is fixed, you can simply choose $m=2$, making $(m+1)^n(m^n-2^n)=0$, and $1^n+2^n$ always divides $0$.

Comment: Sorry, i had forgotten to add that $m\neq 2$, thanks.

Comment: This still leaves open a question whether you want specific $m$, any $m$, or all of them?

Comment: It would improve your Question to cite the "certain text" where the problem was found, possibly as to chapter and page.

Comment: @Ivan, the question asked for any $m$.

Comment: @Ivan, let me try to look for the text online, as i nolonger have it.

Comment: $1^2+2^2+3^2+4^2=30$ divides $(5^2)\times(4^2-2^2)$.